# Security concern

Tags: security

I am constantly checking my logs. Few requests are as follow:

```
POST /admin/Cms_Wysiwyg/...
POST /customer/admin/Cms_Wysiwyg/...
POST /catalog/admin/Cms_Wysiwyg/...
```

I know, these request are security related. Also my site has **custom admin url** and all patches are applied.

My main concern is this:

```
POST /customer/admin/Cms_Wysiwyg/...
POST /catalog/admin/Cms_Wysiwyg/...
```

I don't think (see) there is such url or controller to work this way.

Full log

> 128.199.229.51 - - [25/Oct/2016:11:32:39 +1100] "POST /admin/Cms_Wysiwyg/DELETED/index/ HTTP/1.1" 404 110770
>   "https ://www.mysite.com/admin/Cms_Wysiwyg/DELETED/index/"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"

`customer/admin` should throw 404, so should `catalog/admin`. But I am trying to understand there must be reason for these request I am receiving.

Anyone can point me to right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a blind attack, where people/bots are trying to exploit known vulnerabilities, but your site does not have them, so they get nothing and move on. If you get many of these requests, consider blocking the urls, so that the web server returns a 404 response immediately without bothering Magento.

Comment: Do you mean block urls from htaccess?

Comment: Yes, for example with `RewriteRule /admin/Cms_Wysiwyg/ - [L,R=404]`